# Use of MSVC-compiled Boost binaries in a MinGW-compiled project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, linker, mingw

I've downloaded Boost Binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.56.0/). My project depends on `boost_system` and boost_filesystem, and builds correctly if I add the proper dependencies to Linker Options when using Visual Studio for compilation, but I'm now trying to compile under Code::Blocks (MinGW compiler) and running into the following:

```
"directve `/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1800" /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0" /FAILIFMISMATCH:"RuntimeLibrary=MD_DynamicRelease" /DEFAULTLIB:"msvcprt" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" "
```

Though that's a warning, it keeps me from finding the dependencies, because my project fails to build with `undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'` and plenty of other related undefined references.

Question: Should I compile Boost from source using MinGW, in order to solve my problem?

Of course, I'm using the proper libraries for my build configuration (Release, dynamic runtime library).

Comment: Opinion: Most likely unless you put some MSVC dependence into your project. Boost have a lot of ifdefs for different compilers and the state of standard compliance of each.

Comment: You can't mix C++ compiled with GCC and Visual Studio: they have different C++ ABI implementations, and generate different 'manglings' of identifier names so that linker symbols won't match up. Often C++ compilers aren't completely compatible between different versions of the same compiler too. Yes, you will need to compile both lots of code with the same compiler.

Comment: Yes. You should compile Boost from source using MinGW.

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen. Why don't you guys make a proper answer so I can accept it for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an answser based on the comments posted below my question, just to make things proper.

So, **building boost** from the source code **using the same compiler** (I used TDM-GCC with gcc 4.8.1) **did solve the linking issues**.

As noted by [Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup), one "can't mix C++ compiled with GCC and Visual Studio: they have different C++ ABI implementations, and generate different 'manglings' of identifier names so that linker symbols won't match up."

Additional reference: [Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands)

Comment: I remember vaguely that it should be better with 64-bit applications, some agreement between the vendors.